# Pandas: ¿Cómo hallar todas las "entradas largas" posibles basadas en los datos de OHLC y unas series de precios de límite superior e inferior?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, algoritmos, ciencia-de-datos

Supóngase que tiene un Pandas `df` que contiene los precios OHLC (abreviatura de Open, High, Low, Close) de un activo financiero en particular.

Además, debe considerar otros dos dataframes de Pandas, una de ellas llamado `upper_bound` que contiene una serie de precios que están por encima del precio de cierre, y la otra llamada `lower_bound` que contiene una serie de precios que están por debajo del precio de cierre. .

Todos los datos necesarios se pueden encontrar [aquí](https://github.com/noahverner1995/Data-Dump-Folder/blob/main/StackOverFlowQuestions/All_possible_long_entrries_problem.py).

Todos estas Dataframes de Pandas comparten el mismo índice (tanto de valores como tipo), y así es como se vería la representación gráfica de todos estos datos en un solo gráfico de velas japonesas (*La **tendencia rosa** representa el* `upper_bound`, mientras que la ***tendencia blanca**  representa el* `lower_bound`):

[image: Gráfico APT/USDT]

Se necesita:

1. Averiguar el valor del índice en el que el precio bajo del `df` es menor o igual al valor del límite inferior.
2. Averiguar el siguiente valor del índice en el que el precio máximo de `df` es mayor o igual que el valor del límite superior.
3. Estimar el cambio porcentual desde el primer valor de índice del límite inferior hasta el segundo valor de índice del límite superior.
4. Agregar ese cambio de porcentaje, ese primer valor de índice y ese segundo valor de índice a otro marco de datos llamado `possible_long_entries`.
5. Repitir este proceso hasta que no haya más datos para analizar.

## Mi enfoque (posiblemente malo)

Escribí el siguiente código de Python para resolver este problema:

```
# Find all the possible long entries that could have been made considering the information above
possible_long_entries = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Actual Percentage Change', 'Start Index', 'End Index'])
i=0
while i < (len(df)-1):
    if df['Low Price'][i] <= lower_bound[i]:
        lower_index = i
        j = i + 1
        while j < (len(df)-1):
            if df['High Price'][j] >= upper_bound[j]:
                upper_index = j
                percentage_change = (upper_bound.iat[upper_index] - lower_bound.iat[lower_index]) / lower_bound.iat[lower_index] * 100
                possible_long_entries = possible_long_entries.append({'Actual Percentage Change':percentage_change,'Start Index': lower_index, 'End Index':upper_index},ignore_index=True)
                i = j + 1
                print(i)
                break
            else:
                j += 1
    else:
        i += 1
```

El problema con este código es el hecho de que *más o menos* entra en un bucle infinito cuando `i` es igual a **407**, no estoy seguro de por qué. Después de detener manualmente la ejecución, verifiqué `possible_long_entries` y estos fueron los datos que logró extraer:

```
final_dict = {'Actual Percentage Change': {0: 3.694220620875114, 1: 2.4230128905797654, 2: 2.1254433367789014, 3: 2.9138599524587625, 4: 3.177040784650736, 5: 1.0867515559002843, 6: 0.08567173253550972, 7: 0.19999498819328332, 8: 3.069342080456284, 9: 1.467935498997383, 10: -0.6867540630203672, 11: 2.019389675661748, 12: 3.1057216745256353, 13: 1.758775161828502}, 'Start Index': {0: 17.0, 1: 50.0, 2: 89.0, 3: 106.0, 4: 113.0, 5: 132.0, 6: 169.0, 7: 193.0, 8: 237.0, 9: 271.0, 10: 285.0, 11: 345.0, 12: 374.0, 13: 401.0}, 'End Index': {0: 38.0, 1: 62.0, 2: 101.0, 3: 109.0, 4: 118.0, 5: 146.0, 6: 185.0, 7: 206.0, 8: 251.0, 9: 281.0, 10: 322.0, 11: 361.0, 12: 396.0, 13: 406.0}}

possible_long_entries = pd.DataFrame(final_dict)
```

¿Podría obtener algo de ayuda aquí, por favor?

Comment: Creo que llevas como un año con tu programa de las velas japonesas xD. Al utilizar `pandas` es recomendable **no** utilizar ciclos (Por ejemplo `for`) para iterar en los elementos, hay métodos optimizados que trabajan con el `dataset` rápida y eficientemente. En la mayoría de los casos, si lo que quieres hacer crees que se puede hacer con un ciclo entonces es el camino incorrecto (O el que va a tardar más y tener mayor impacto al procesador). En esos casos, si no hay un método directo que realice la tarea entonces `apply` podría ser una buena opción, como último recurso sería utilizar ciclos.

Comment: Hola @NoahVerner, si no ne equivoco, el problema es que dentro del **if** que está en el bucle interno, no hay ningún **j += 1** está dentro del **else**, por lo tanto si el programa no pasa por ese **else**, tendrás un bucle infinito...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya lo resolví. El código de abajo funciona asumiendo que ya hubiesen copiado y pegado los datos **OHLC Price**, **upper bound**, **lower bound** provistos en este [este link](https://github.com/noahverner1995/Data-Dump-Folder/blob/main/StackOverFlowQuestions/All_possible_long_entrries_problem.py). Estoy abierto a aprender una mejor forma de hacerlo que produzca el mismo resultado.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Wed Feb  1 03:11:46 2023

@author: Noah
"""

import pandas as pd
from pandas import Timestamp
from numpy import nan
import mplfinance as mpf

def set_DateTimeIndex(df_trading_pair):
    df_trading_pair = df_trading_pair.set_index('Start Date', inplace=False)
    # Rename the column names for best practices
    df_trading_pair.rename(columns = { "Open Price" : 'Open',
                                       "High Price" : 'High',
                                       "Low Price" : 'Low',
                                       "Close Price" :'Close',
                              }, inplace = True)
    return df_trading_pair

### Here you assign the data to the variables `dict`, `df`, `dict_upper`, `upper_bound`, `dict_lower`, `lower_bound` ###

# trading pair name
trading_pair = "APTUSDT"

# Calculate moving average and std deviation of the close price

window_size = 14
rolling_mean = df['Close Price'].rolling(window=window_size).mean()
rolling_std = df['Close Price'].rolling(window=window_size).std()

# Calculate the upper and lower bounds of the close price based on the moving average and std deviation

upper_bound = rolling_mean + 2 * rolling_std
lower_bound = rolling_mean - 2 * rolling_std

# Create masks to know at which indices the df["Low Price"] was equal or lower than the lower bound
# as well as which indices the df["High Price"] was equal or greater than the upper bound

mask_low = df["Low Price"] <= lower_bound
mask_high = df["High Price"] >= upper_bound

upper_indices = list(mask_high[mask_high].index)
lower_indices = list(mask_low[mask_low].index)

# Now figure out which had been the possible long entries that had been made using the information above
# Keep in mind that this assumes the long entries made reached exactly the corresponding values of the `upper_bound`

data = {"Start Index": [lower_indices[0]], "Endt Index": []}
entry = lower_indices[0]

data = {"Start Index": [], "End Index": []}

entry = lower_indices[0]
for i in range(len(upper_indices)):
    exit = upper_indices[i]
    if exit > entry:
        data["Start Index"].append(entry)
        data["End Index"].append(exit)
        next_entries = [x for x in lower_indices if x > entry and x > exit]
        if len(next_entries) > 0:
            entry = next_entries[0]
        else:
            break
    
possible_long_entries= pd.DataFrame(data)
possible_long_entries['Bullish Percentage Change'] = (upper_bound[possible_long_entries['End Index']].values - lower_bound[possible_long_entries['Start Index']].values)/(lower_bound[possible_long_entries['Start Index']].values)*100

# Mark the possible long entries, in order to do this first create an NaN df that contains the same indices as the original df
# Then assign to each index of the possible_long_entries df its corresponding price from the lower_bound
df_mark_entry_points = pd.DataFrame([float('nan')]*len(df),index=df.index,columns=['Bullish Entries'])
for ix,val in zip(possible_long_entries['Start Index'].values,lower_bound[possible_long_entries['Start Index']].values):
   df_mark_entry_points.loc[ix] = val

# Mark the possible take-profits assuming the highest price would have reached the upper_bound, in order to do this first create an NaN df that contains the same indices as the original df
# Then assign to each index of the possible_long_entries df its corresponding price from the upper_bound
df_mark_tp_points = pd.DataFrame([float('nan')]*len(df),index=df.index,columns=['Bullish Entries'])
for ix,val in zip(possible_long_entries['End Index'].values,upper_bound[possible_long_entries['End Index']].values):
   df_mark_tp_points.loc[ix] = val


# Store the plots of upper and lower bounds as well as the possible long entries for later use
plots_to_add = [mpf.make_addplot(upper_bound,color='#F93BFF'), mpf.make_addplot(lower_bound,color='white'), mpf.make_addplot(df_mark_entry_points,type='scatter',markersize=50,marker='^', color='#00FFE0'), mpf.make_addplot(df_mark_tp_points,type='scatter',markersize=50,marker='v', color='#FFF000')]

# Estimate the percentage change from the lower bound to the uppder bound
bullish_percentage_change_between_bounds = round((upper_bound-lower_bound)/lower_bound*100,2)
bullish_percentage_change_between_bounds.rename('Bulllish Pct Chg', inplace = True)

#If the skewness is between -0.5 and 0.5, the data are fairly symmetrical
#If the skewness is between -1 and — 0.5 or between 0.5 and 1, the data are moderately skewed
#If the skewness is less than -1 or greater than 1, the data are highly skewed

#Kurtosis applied to Financial Markets: https://www.investopedia.com/terms/k/kurtosis.asp

skewness_value = bullish_percentage_change_between_bounds.skew()
kurtosis_value = bullish_percentage_change_between_bounds.kurt()

if (abs(skewness_value) > 0.5):
    
    # Use the median to properly estimate the return on investment per trade
    expected_roi = bullish_percentage_change_between_bounds.median()
    if kurtosis_value > 3:
        print(f'The bullish percentage change between bounds follows a Leptokurtic distribution, and the expected roi is {expected_roi}%')
    elif kurtosis_value < 3:
        print(f'The bullish percentage change between bounds follows a Platikurtic distribution, and the expected roi is {expected_roi}%')

elif (abs(skewness_value) <= 0.5):
    
    # Use the mean to properly estimate the return on investment per trade
    expected_roi = bullish_percentage_change_between_bounds.mean()
    if kurtosis_value > 3:
        print(f'The bullish percentage change between bounds follows a Leptokurtic distribution, and the expected roi is {expected_roi}%')
    elif kurtosis_value < 3:
        print(f'The bullish percentage change between bounds follows a Platikurtic distribution, and the expected roi is {expected_roi}%')
    
print()
# Plot the Close Price, Moving average, upper and lower bounds using a line chart.

# Plotting
# Create my own `marketcolors` style:
mc = mpf.make_marketcolors(up='#2fc71e',down='#ed2f1a',inherit=True)
# Create my own `MatPlotFinance` style:
s  = mpf.make_mpf_style(base_mpl_style=['bmh', 'dark_background'],marketcolors=mc, y_on_right=True)    

# Plot it
candlestick_plot, axlist = mpf.plot(df_trading_pair_date_time_index,
                    figsize=(40,20),
                    figratio=(10, 6),
                    type="candle",
                    style=s,
                    tight_layout=True,
                    datetime_format = '%b %d, %H:%M:%S',
                    ylabel = "Precio ($)",
                    returnfig=True,
                    show_nontrading=True,
                    warn_too_much_data=870, # Silence the Too Much Data Plot Warning by setting a value greater than the amount of rows you want to be plotted
                    addplot = plots_to_add # Add the upper and lower bounds plots as well as the bullish entries to the main plot
                    )
# Add Title
symbol = trading_pair.replace("USDT", "")+"/"+"USDT"
axlist[0].set_title(f"{symbol} - 15m", fontsize=45, style='italic', fontfamily='fantasy')
```

## Output:

The bullish percentage change between bounds follows a Leptokurtic distribution, and the expected roi is 3.57%

[image: salida final]